# Particular Sigma Sequence & Series Evaluation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm sure that somewhere in my work of evaluating the below problem there has been either an algebraic misstep or incorrect conclusion of a given series rule. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{3}{n}[(1+\frac{3i}{n})^3)-2(1+\frac{3i}{n})]$$
Which was then simplified to:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}[\frac{3}{n}+\frac{12i}{n^2}+\frac{81i^2}{n^3}+\frac{81i^3}{n^4}-\frac{6}{n}+\frac{9i}{n^2}]$$
And...
$$\frac{3}{n}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1+\frac{12}{n^2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i+\frac{81}{n^3}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2+\frac{81}{n^4}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3-\frac{6}{n}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1-\frac{9}{n^2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i$$
Which evaluates to:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}[(\frac{3n}{n})+(12*\frac{n}{n}*\frac{n+1}{n})+(\frac{13.5}{n}*\frac{n+1}{n}*\frac{2n+1}{n})+(\frac{20.25}{n}*n*\frac{n+1}{n}*\frac{n+1}{n})-(\frac{6n}{n})-(9*\frac{n}{n}*\frac{n+1}{n})]$$
And...

=(3+12+20.25-6-9)

=20.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{3}{n}\left[\left(1+\frac{3i}{n}\right)^3-2\left(1+\frac{3i}{n}\right)\right]$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{3}{n}\left(\frac{27 i^3}{n^3}+\frac{27 i^2}{n^2}+\frac{3 i}{n}-1\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{81 i^3}{n^4}+\frac{81 i^2}{n^3}+\frac{9 i}{n^2}-\frac{3}{n}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{81}{n^4}\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^3+\frac{81}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2+\frac{9}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} i-\frac{3}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1=$$
$$=\frac{81}{n^4}\frac{1}{4} n^2 (n+1)^2+\frac{81}{n^3}\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1)+\frac{9}{n^2}\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-\frac{3}{n}n=$$
$$=\frac{81}{4n^2} (n+1)^2+\frac{27}{2n^2}(n+1) (2 n+1)+\frac{9}{2n}(n+1)-3=\frac{3 \left(65 n^2+114 n+45\right)}{4 n^2}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{195 n^2+342 n+135}{4 n^2}=\color{red}{\frac{195}{4}}$$